# dice probability

Tags: probability

how do you calculate the probability of rolling a particular number on a dice on a particular roll. For instance you want a six but the first roll is not, the second roll is not but third roll is a six.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $5$ choices for the first and second roll but $1$ choice for the third roll, and $6^3$ outcomes so the probability is  $(5\times 5\times 1)/6^3$. In general this becomes $5^k/6^n$ where $n$ is the number of tosses and $n-k$ the number of required $6$ faces.

Comment: so is this correct? 25./(6.**3). I used an algorithm that used random choice to calculate the probability and got 0.116051 but the answer was supposed to be in reduced fraction so I thought my logic was wrong somehow but the result of 25./(6.**3)= 0.11574... Am I still missing something?

Comment: Well the values are really close. The other answers are also saying its $5^2/6^3$.

Comment: I must have interpreted the question incorrectly somehow. I got it wrong but could not figure out why!

Comment: Can you explain this algorithm you are using, and why you are certain it gives the correct result?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How about you write a program that lists all the possible outputs and selects the ones whose first $2$ entries are not $6$ while the $3$rd is, it should not be too hard.

Comment: I pick three random numbers and store in a list if choice[0] != n and choice[1] != n and choice[2] ==1 I increment  a counter and finally divide the counter by num of trial. It is not the exact result, it was the only way I could figure it out. The question asked to put the answer in reduced fraction form, I think that is why I questioned the result.

Comment: that is what I did.

Comment: When you pick $3$ numbers at random, you are not guaranteed to get all the cases. Fill in an arrays with all $216$ combinations and count how many have non $6$ in the first $2$ entries and $6$ in the 3rd.

Comment: The algorithm's answer was very close to the answer using your formula, I think the issue is just how I interpreted the question. Picking three numbers from a list of the number 1 to 6 should work. They were different each trial for up to  5000000 trials.I will try your suggestion just to see how close it gets the the answer using a seed compared to my first algorithm.

Comment: you are correct, second answer is your suggest algorithm.                             0.116051
0.115740740741

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand what you want: this is called Geometric probability. In this case the probability not to toss $6$ is $\frac{5}{6}$. Assuming the dice is fair and and rolls are independent all you need is 
$$
P(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p
$$
where $1-p=\frac{5}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of **not** getting a number $a$ on a six-sided dice is $\mathrm{Pr}(a)=\dfrac{5}{6}$. The probability of getting $a$ in the first roll is $1-\mathrm{Pr}(a)$. However, see that whether or not you get $a$ in the first roll does not affect the second roll, i.e., rolling a dice is an event independent of the previous roll(s). Thus, the probability of getting $a$ in the $n$th roll is equivalent to getting $a$ in the first roll, i.e., $1-\mathrm{Pr}(a)$. (However, if you want the probability of getting $a$ in all $n$ rolls, the probability is $1-(\mathrm{Pr}(a))^n$.)

Comment: The problem wanted the probability of not getting it on the first two rolls  but getting it on the third roll exactly. As I said in another comment I used an algorithm to calculate the P over 1000000 trials but as it was supposed to be in reduced fraction I could not use my result to answer but using the logic how I see it here I don't get an answer where I can use reduced fraction either. I think I have been out of school for too long!